# Namespace conflict in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I am developing an Android App using Unity3d. I have already added [Socket-io](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/socket.io-unity)

Now I wanted to add [Fingers](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/fingers-touch-gestures-for-unity-41076) from AssetStore. Once I import it to my project I get few errors like this:

> CS0433 The type exists in both 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and "WebSocket4Net, Version=0.14.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb4e154b696bf72a"

The error comes from `System.Action<T1,T2,T3>()` and `System.Func()`

After some investigations I found that `System.Action` was not part of .Net2.0 but was added in later version (not sure if  .Net3.0 or .Net3.5)

From my understanding that the problems comes from WebSoccket4Net which adds these function to .NET2.0 and that the fact that the player setting uses .NET2.0 for API but .NET3.5 for scripting.

I even tried to edit the source code of [WebSocket4Net](https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net) by changing the namespace, but it failed, because the code in fact 4 versions for different .NET Versions. `System.Action()` and `System.Func()` are declared internally only in .NET2.0 and the Standard functions are used for the later .NET versions. So updating the source code break the cross compatibility

Can any one suggest how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already implement things using the one or the other framework ? Hence why he is telling you it is defined in both ? You should be able to specify from which package to use on your call.

Comment: I didn't added any custom code to any of the frameworks. The problem in that WebScoket4Net redefines the functions, using namespace 'system' which raised the conflict when added to Unity